# How to access individual elements from .xib file loaded into the view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a .xib file for a view controller and a corresponding Swift file. On click of a button another xib is loaded to show a popup view.

I load the popup view's xib file like this:

```
let myPopupView : UIView = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("myPopupView",
                                                     owner: nil,
                                                     options:nil)?.first as? UIView)!
```

Now the popup view has a set of labels for which I want to set selectors. How to do this?

Comment: What selectors do you want to set?

Comment: Are you adding any control events on label. If YES, it won't work for labels. You should rather try adding gestures.

Comment: My mistake. Not selectors. `UIGestureRecognizer` s were what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set selectors on views. What you can do is either use buttons or add `UIGestureRecognizer`s (probably tap gesture recognizers) on your views.

You can either make your view a custom subclass of UIView that has IBOutlets to its subviews, or make the file's owner of your XIB file be the view controller that it's being loaded into, and then wire up outlets from the subviews directly into the view controller. The second approach won't work for a situation like a table view cell where you're adding multiple instances of this view to your view controller. In that case you'd need use the first approach of making your top-level view a custom subclass of `UIView`